# How do I increase performance of jython Code?

Tags: performance, jvm, jython

I'm currently working in an environment within a JVM which only allows two script languages: groovy and jython. The scripts I write rely heavily on jdbc queries (querying and iterating over result sets) and nested loops.

I usually write each script first in jython, then in groovy, in order to compare performance. Groovy always beats jython (makes sense, since groovy is essentially java source code right?), despite the code performing the same tasks.

I would, however, prefer to use jython. So I researched parameters that could speed up jython code in general. I tweaked the xmx and xms jvm parameters to no avail. I am also in the process of tweaking the garbage collector.

I was wondering if you could provide me with some jython specific jvm tuning advice to improve performance. I'm grateful for any lessons you might have learnt improving jython performance.

Comment: Where is the database? Unless it's on the same machine (and perhaps even then), optimising the round trips and queries sounds more likely to be fruitful... More generally, have you measured the current performance, determined that it's unsatisfactory, and pinpointed the difference between languages as the culprit?

Comment: The database roundtrip times are very similar and have already been optimized. Yes, I have measured performance and the biggest performance difference happens when iterating through iterable objects. Any kind of large loop and nested loop creates the biggest difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, kotlin is also a scripting language under the JVM. Kotlin has a scripting language mode , it is also used as the DSL of gradle.

Due to the late appearance, the design of syntax and performance should be better. You can try it.